# WPF TextBox Property Inheritance

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties, attached-properties

Why this works:

```
<StackPanel TextBlock.FontWeight="Bold">
    <!-- All text boxes inside have their text in bold -->
    <TextBox Width="100" Height="24" Text="AaBbCc"  />
</StackPanel>
```

and this does not?

```
<StackPanel TextBox.TextDecorations="Underline">
    <TextBox Width="100" Height="24" Text="AaBbCc"  />
</StackPanel>
```

`error MC3015: The attached property 'TextBox.TextDecorations' is not defined on 'StackPanel' or one of its base classes.`

But `FontWeight` property is also not defined on `StackPanel`! So why they behave differently?

Comment: What about TextBlock.TextDecorations="Underline"??? You're using that in the first piece of code.

Answer (score 2):

As it says -- TextDecorations is not AttachedProperty !

if you want to apply this to multiple, there are other ways like style setting or making it a template